# Update query works for all columns except one

Tags: c#, sql

I have an update query in my .xsd file as below:

```
UPDATE Factors 
SET    CodeFactor = @CodeFactor, Date = @Date, MobileNumber = @MobileNumber, 
       Description= @Description, TotalPrice = @TotalPrice, 
       ShouldPayPrice = @ShouldPayPrice 
       WHERE ID = @Original_ID; 
SELECT   ID, CodeFactor, Date, PersonName, MobileNumber, Description, TotalPrice, 
         ShouldPayPrice, PaidPrice, Settlement, Kind 
FROM     Factors 
WHERE    ID = @Original_ID
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

and I use it in one of my form as below:

```
Fact.UpdateQuery(txtShomareFactor.Text.Trim(), fdpDate.Text.Trim(),
                 txtMobile.Text.Trim(), txtSharheKharid.Text,
                 Convert.ToInt64(txtJameKol.Text.Replace(",", "").Trim()),
                 Convert.ToInt64(txtMablagheGhabelePardakht.Text.Replace(",", "").Trim()), 
                 IDFactorTOShowDetails);
```

It updates all columns except the description column!

Comment: TRY ENCLOSING FIELD NAMES IN [] like [MobileNumber] = @MobileNumber

Comment: I did it but it didn't work again. :( any other suggestion?

Comment: Does `@description` has some value at the time of update? Try debugging. And is it a valid value for description column?

Comment: It was a mistake from other parts of programm and it resolved.... sorry to get your times ... thx for your helps...

Comment: @marc_s, out of curiosity, is a field in sql terminology not a column?

Comment: @nawfal: well - strictly speaking, a database table has **rows** and **columns**, and an object in memory (e.g. your .NET object) is a **record** and has **fields**. But devs are mixing up these terms quite frequently - but I think one should be aware of those differences, be precise and use the correct term when describing stuff

Comment: @marc_s thanks, thats clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try like [Description]=@Description since Description word should be a kind of special keyword in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

First try to check your code and trace it, and take look at SQL Profiler to get what is send to sql from your application.
also note that Description is keyword in sql server. use it between [ ] or use table name before column name. 
like `Factors.[Description]`
Overally change your query as below:

```
UPDATE Factors 
SET    CodeFactor = @CodeFactor, [Date] = @Date, MobileNumber = @MobileNumber, 
       [Description]= @Description, TotalPrice = @TotalPrice, 
       ShouldPayPrice = @ShouldPayPrice 
       WHERE ID = @Original_ID; 
SELECT   ID, CodeFactor, [Date], PersonName, MobileNumber, [Description], TotalPrice, 
         ShouldPayPrice, PaidPrice, Settlement, Kind 
FROM     Factors 
WHERE    ID = @Original_ID
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```